# Batch showing zero records processed ,is there a way to throw exception if no Records found in Querylocator

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, batchapexerrorevent

here is batch code which is executing currently showing as zero records processed in  AysncApexJob , no errors though ,what i want is whenever **batch find Zero record in SOQL of start method** then batch should fail with exception or show error message

```
global class CaseCopyBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {
                private List<Batch_Case_Type__c> processedRecords;
            global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
                processedRecords = new List<Batch_Case_Type__c>();
                // collect the batches of records or objects to be passed to execute        
                String query = 'SELECT Case__c, Lvl_1__c, Lvl_2__c,Lvl_3__c,UniqueGUID__c  FROM Batch_Case_Type__c WHERE createddate = today AND IsProcessed__c = false';
                return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
            }
            global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Batch_Case_Type__c> exeList) {   
                // process each batch of records
                List<Case_Type__c> listCTD = new List<Case_Type__c>();
               
                for(Batch_Case_Type__c exe : exeList)
                {        
                    listCTD.add(new Case_Type__c(Case__c=exe.Case__c,Lvl_1__c=exe.Lvl_1__c,Lvl_2__c=exe.Lvl_2__c,Lvl_3__c=exe.Lvl_3__c,CaseUniqueGUID__c=exe.UniqueGUID__c));
                   exe.IsProcessed__c = true;    
                }
                try {
                    
                    insert listCTD;
                    //only successful batches will be processed 
                    processedRecords.addAll(exeList);
                    update processedRecords;
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    System.debug(e);
                }
            }   
            global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
               
              
            }
            }
```

Your response is highly appreciated

Regards
Fiona

Comment: Just FYI batches do not need to be `global` (and should not be).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would solve this

```
public class CaseCopyBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful, 
                                      Database.RaisesPlatformEvents {
 Integer recordCount = 0;

 public Database.QueryLocator start(BatchableContext bc) {
   return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
 }

 public void execute(BatchableContext bc, Sobject[] records) {
     recordCount += records.size();
     .. work
 }

 public void finish(BatchableContext bc) {
      if (recordCount == 0) {
         throw new MyException('No records found in job X');
      }
 }
```

then implement a [trigger subscriber](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_platformevents.htm?q=raisesPlatformevents) on `BatchApexErrorEvent` that logs the error and does whatever else you need done, like notify someone, try to restart, etc.  `BatchApexErrorEvent` will capture your exception type and message

This approach is powerful in that it gives you visibility into not just thrown exceptions but also uncatchable exceptions like Limits errors.

It also follows best practices wherein batch jobs that fetch zero records should just flow through to finish() where you can decide whether no records is normal or not.